# How do you configure the RunJettyRun Eclipse plugin to use logback?

Tags: java, slf4j, logback, runjettyrun

After installing the RunJettyRun plugin in Eclipse Juno and having my application successfully run, I can't figure out how to change the logger to Logback.

There are some instructions on the web, but they're all either incomplete or very confusing.

I've succesfully configured jetty-start to use `logback` by including `logback-classic` as a dependency in the pom.xml file.